# i-search -- How to know for sure whether focus is still in the minibuffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I use i-search forwards / backwards a million times a day, but I still haven't figured out how to know for sure whether focus is still in the minibuffer.

I believe my confusion stems from a failed search followed by an attempt to modify the search parameter, and that is when the document gets modified by mistake because focus has already left the minibuffer -- however, I am tricked into thinking the minibuffer is still active because my search term is still displayed -- e.g.,

- `Failing wrapped I-search backward: abcdefg`
- `Failing overwrapped I-search:  abcedfg`
- `Wrapped I-search: abcedfg`
- `Overwrapped I-search backward: abcefg`
- `Failing wrapped I-search:  abcedfg`

Any ideas on how I could tweak / modify i-search forwards / backwards to prevent this from happening?

Maybe the document modeline could change to inactive whenever isearch is active, and the modeline could update to active as soon as the isearch function finishes.  And perhaps a message -- "the function isearch has exited."

I'm at the point were I am thinking about making my document read-only while I am i-searching, but of course that would be overkill.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thing is, focus *isn't* in the minibuffer during an isearch, unless you use `M-e` to edit the search string; it's in your document.  I'm definitely one who appreciates plenty of contextual hints, but I've never found the isearch indications indadequate (`Isearch` in the modeline, `I-search:` below it, highlighting of the active search result, highlighting of other search results).

When you use, say, `RET` to exit an isearch, the status line does display "Mark saved where search started".  Unless you have set `search-edit-option` to a non-default value, anything but an isearch-specific command or typing will exit the search.

If you do want more indications of an isearch in progress, you can use `isearch-mode-hook` and `isearch-mode-end-hook`.  For example, to change the modeline colors:

```
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'isearch-mode-line-face-remap-cookie)
                 (face-remap-add-relative
                  'mode-line '((:foreground "ivory" :background "red") mode-line)))))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook
          (lambda ()
            (face-remap-remove-relative isearch-mode-line-face-remap-cookie)))
```

Or if that still isn't high-visibility enough, you could change the background color of the buffer's text:

```
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'isearch-default-face-remap-cookie)
                 (face-remap-add-relative
                  'default '((:background "yellow") default)))))

(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook
          (lambda ()
            (face-remap-remove-relative isearch-default-face-remap-cookie)))
```

By the way, if you haven't tried it, press `C-h m` when you're in an `isearch`; there's a lot of bindings that let you customize your search, of which I was unaware for my first ~15 years of Emacs use.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for -- thank you so very much!  And, thank you for clarifying my misperception about where focus was being placed during the isearch.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: I had also never noticed the word `Isearch` in the modeline -- thank you.

Answer (score 2):

@NicholasRiley clarified things well. To add just a bit, in case it helps:

- [Isearch+](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/IsearchPlus) (library [`isearch+.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/isearch%2b.el)) uses the mode-line and the Isearch prompt to show more info about the search state:

  - Case-sensitivity is indicated in the mode line minor-mode lighter: `ISEARCH` for case-insensitive; `Isearch` for case-sensitive.
  - The lighter is highlighted when search has wrapped around.
  - Parts of the prompt are highlighted, to indicate the type of search: regexp, word, multiple-buffer, and whether searching has wrapped around the buffer.
- With library [`oneonone.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/oneonone.el), the background of the standalone minibuffer frame has a different color during Isearch. Even if you do not want a standalone minibuffer, the general idea might help. It uses these hooks:

```lisp
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook     '1on1-color-isearch-minibuffer-frame)
(add-hook 'isearch-mode-end-hook '1on1-color-minibuffer-frame-on-exit)
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook '1on1-color-minibuffer-frame-on-setup)
(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook  '1on1-color-minibuffer-frame-on-exit)
```

Comment: Thank you very much -- I will take a look into the options you've mentioned.